# How to set a NavLink as active using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom, and I need to make red a link when the url match, in my up I have two urls `/` => home and `/map`.

With the current code, I am able to route to different page but the `NavLink` is not being highlighted when the url is changed in the browser. Any ideas how to fix it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = ({ onClick, id, title, tooltip, url }) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={onClick} alt={tooltip}>
      { <Route path={url} exact children={({ match }) => (

        <div style={match ? {color: 'red'} : {}}>
          {match ? '> ' : ''}<NavLink to={url}>{title}</NavLink>
        </div>
  )} />}
    </div >
  )
}

export default Navigation

const Root = ({ store }) => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Forecast} />
            <Route exact path='/map' component={Map} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
```

Comment: Yes correct, I want to mark as active the link which map the URL. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is bit confusing. But if you want to highlight the active link which is navigated you can simply add **activeClassName** to your NavLink. Something like this

```
<NavLink to={url} exact activeClassName="activeLink" style=>{title}</NavLink>
```

CSS for activeLink:

```
.activeLink {
    color: red;
 }
```

* **react-router-dom: "^4.1.2"**

Comment: I have tried this approach, but the url is not being marked activated properly

Comment: I am adding my router file, could you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This works for this common errors:

- 'isActive' is not defined  no-undef
- activeClassName is not working in NavLink

In React Router v6, activeClassName will be removed and you should use the function className to apply classnames to either active or inactive NavLink components.

[Reference is here.](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Use normally the imports like:

```
import { NavLink, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```

and in NavLinks use:

```
<NavLink
  to="/text"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Text
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

for react Navlink a simple

```
a.active{color:red;}
```

will work automatically, with Navlink even cursor:pointer is by default grabbing. no